# Animations on scroll causing there to be white space on mobile devices

Tags: html, animation

I have added an animation library to my HTML code, but for some reason it causes there to be white space to the right side of the screen on mobile devices. On desktops/laptops there is no white space, but I am not sure why it shows whitespace on mobile devices.

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css" 
 />
</head>

<body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js"></script>
<script>
  AOS.init();
</script>

<div data-aos="fade-left">
 <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

make data-aos-once=true
it will make it appear once but it will make the right space disapear its always there because its always active

Comment: until i can figure out another solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm using React & TailwindCSS so I just added "overflow-x-hidden" to each and every component in their parent element

```
<div className="overflow-x-hidden">
  <div data-aos="fade-in">
     <Component />
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use pure css as well via adding the below code in the parent element

```
.parentElement{
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to Fix Unnecessary Horizontal Scrollbars on Screens of All Sizes

I recently encountered an issue where an unnecessary horizontal scrollbar and right space were appearing on screens of various sizes, regardless of whether it was a small mobile device or a larger desktop monitor. This problem occurred when the content on a webpage exceeded the width of the viewport, and it was further exacerbated when animations were applied, such as elements entering the viewport from the left or right side, or when zooming out.

I want to share the solution with you all in case anyone else faces a similar issue.

To fix this, I used a combination of CSS and a media query. The solution not only addresses the unnecessary horizontal scrollbar but also works seamlessly on screens of all sizes (u can change max-width: --px).

Let's take a look at the CSS code:

CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
HTML, body {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}}

html, body {
width: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;}
```

Explanation:

> The media query @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) targets
> screens with a maximum width of 768 pixels. This includes small
> screens such as mobile devices. Inside the media query, we set the
> width property of the html and body elements to 100%, ensuring they
> span the entire viewport width. We also set the overflow-x property to
> hidden, which hides any content that exceeds the width of the viewport
> and prevents the horizontal scrollbar from appearing. By applying
> these styles, we can effectively eliminate the unnecessary horizontal
> scrollbar issue on screens of all sizes, be they small screens or
> desktop screens.